# Jquery doesn't find div to append to when the variable in $('#div'+variable) contains spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to append divs using jQuery from a function's input values but noticed that I wasn't getting anything but the main div appended to the body:

```
var the_key = "AAA AA"; //put here as an example
$('body').append('<div class="chart_canvas" id="div_'+ the_key +'" />');
$('#div_' + the_key).append('<div id="d3_canvas'+ the_key +'" />');
```

It works if the_key = "AAAAA".

My not so good attempt at adding quotation marks wasn't really successful and did end up with an error (unrecognized expression) as the quotation marks end up in the expression:

```
$('#div_' + "'" + the_key + "'").append('<div id="d3_canvas'+ the_key +'" />');
```

Is there any way that I can do this? The object that I'm reading these "the_key" values from do all contain spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `id` values cannot have spaces in them. It's just about [the only restriction on `id` values in HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-id) (other than that they must be unique).
2. Separately, CSS [ID *selectors*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors) cannot contain unescaped spaces either (because a space is a *descendant combinator*). But that doesn't matter because #1. :-)

Use a valid ID, and provided it doesn't have any characters that are allowed in HTML `id`s but not CSS ID selectors (or you properly escape those characters), concatenation without quotes will work.

Comment: just want to ask since this is about invalid ID starting an ID with number is it valid?

Comment: @guradio: I'm afraid I can't make out that sentence. The OP's ID doesn't start with a digit, so the CSS issue with an ID selector starting with a digit is irrelevant. The issue here is spaces, which are invalid in **both** HTML `id`s and CSS ID selectors.

Comment: it was my own question. sometimes i see OP here with ID starting with number or sometimes special character. I just want to know what to respond on those OP

Comment: @guradio: Ah! The answer is: An ID starting with a digit is absolutely fine in HTML (the spec has varied, but current spec says it's fine and browsers have always been fine with it). But a CSS ID selector cannot start with an unescaped digit, which makes IDs starting with digits a pain if you're going to select then with CSS selectors (in style sheets or JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

A space in ID is a "problem" for jQuery. Try to Escape it:

```
<script>
  // document.getElementById or similar
  document.getElementById('AAA AA');
  // document.querySelector or similar
  $('#AAA\\ AA');
</script>
```

You could also use the attribute selector like this:

```
<script>
  $("*[id='AAA AA']");
</script>
```

Comment: A space in an `id` is invalid, full stop. Not even HTML allows it.

Comment: As far as I know in HTML5 all restrictions about allowed characters inside the ID attribute where remove. Now ID is a normal attribute like all the others

Comment: No, as I said in my answer (with citation), [HTML does not allow spaces](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-id): *"When specified on HTML elements, the id attribute value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element’s tree and must contain at least one character. **The value must not contain any space characters.**"* *(my emphasis)*. There's no need for "as far as I know" when we have specifications to refer to. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Spaces are not legal characters of an [id attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute) value in HTML.

Even though it might "work" in certain situations there is no guarantee that it always will.

```js
console.log('test', document.getElementById('test'));
console.log('te st', document.getElementById('te st'));

console.log('jQuery test', $('#test').length);
console.log('jQuery te st', $('#te st').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">test</div>

<div id="te st">te st</div>
```